# OneJar Expand with (or without) sbt-onejar

Tags: jar, jetty, executable-jar, onejar, sbt-onejar

Is there a way to tell the sbt-onejar SBT plugin to produce a JAR in such way that the `.class` files of my project are in "expanded" form and not under `lib/myproject.jar`?

Alternatively, is it possible to tell sbt-onejar to produce a JAR that, when it's loaded, it actually unpacks/expands the nested JARs into a temporary folder and loads them from there, so that things like `getResource(...)` return paths to physical files as opposed to `jar:file:...` URLs?

Alternativel, I'd also happy with any vanilla OneJar solutions that help me produce a fat JAR wherein my own `.class` files would be directly under the fat JAR as opposed to under `lib/myproject.jar`.

I'm asking because Jetty does not seem to be able to load JSP files from inside of nested JAR files. There does seem to be a workaround by using a custom resource loader (see http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-users/msg01174.html for a report of the same problem and the workaround) but I don't seem to be able to get my servlets to actually use the overridden `getResource` method provided in the workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having read sbt-onejar's source code:

```
packageOptions in oneJar ++=
  Seq(sbt.Package.ManifestAttributes(
    new java.util.jar.Attributes.Name("One-Jar-Expand") -> "some-file.txt"))
```

However, I've realized using OneJar with Jetty is quite a problematic beast due to how Jetty loads JSP files—[doesn't seem to work with nested JARs](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-users/msg01174.html)—so I'm looking into alternatives now.

**EDIT:** I've found https://github.com/xerial/sbt-pack and it seems to achieve the same effect as OneJar with the difference of being standard and thus free of problems, *much* faster, more customizable, and allows defining of convenient custom program entry points.